# Regular expression to find a series of uppercase words in a string

Tags: python, regex

```
text = "This is a TEXT CONTAINING UPPER CASE WORDS and lower case words. This is a SECOND SENTENCE."

pattern = '[A-Z]+[A-Z]+[A-Z]*[\s]+'
```

`re.findall(pattern, text)` gives an output -->

```
['TEXT ', 'CONTAINING ', 'UPPER ', 'CASE ', 'WORDS ', 'SECOND ', 'SENTENCE ']
```

However, I want an output something like this -->

```
['TEXT CONTAINING UPPER CASE WORDS', 'SECOND SENTENCE']
```

Comment: If you determine a sentence as a series of words then a full stop, just split thew original text .split(".") , then use each element of the list into the re.findall

Comment: What if you have sentences like: `This is YOUR FIRST sentence WITH UPPERCASE words. This IS A second.`? Would that still be two elements? Or do you want to seperate the element of the first sentence in two elements?

Comment: @JvdV expected output would be ['YOUR FIRST', 'WITH UPPERCASE', 'IS A']

Comment: @tomgalpin I assume the performance will take a blow.

Comment: `[A-Z]+[A-Z]+[A-Z]*` is better written `[A-Z]+` and `[\s]+` --> `\s+`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
\b[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XyMdgv/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `[A-Z]+`: Match a word comprising only uppercase letters
- `(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*`: Match 1+ whitespace followed by another word with uppercase letters. Match this group 0 or more times
- `\b`: Word boundary

**Code:**

```
>>> s = 'This is a TEXT CONTAINING UPPER CASE WORDS and lower case words. This is a SECOND SENTENCE';
>>> print (re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*\b', s))
['TEXT CONTAINING UPPER CASE WORDS', 'SECOND SENTENCE']
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked well for me, but I had to do: re.findall(r"\b[A-Z]\w*",string)

Answer (score 1):

1. Improving regex, you want at least 2 uppercase letter, so use the dedicated syntax `{2,}` for *2 or more*, and use word boundary to be sure to catch the whole word

   ```
   r'\b[A-Z]{2,}\b'
   ```
2. Do the job for each sentence : find them with a basic regex, and for each sentence, look for the uppercase words, then save them in an array by joining with a space

   ```
   result = []
   sentences = re.findall("[^.]+.", text)
   for sentence in sentences:
       uppercase = re.findall(pattern, sentence)
       result.append(" ".join(uppercase))
   print(result)  # ['TEXT CONTAINING UPPER CASE WORDS', 'SECOND SENTENCE']
   ```

In a list-comprehension, it looks like

```
res = [" ".join(re.findall(pattern, sentence)) for sentence in re.findall("[^.]+.", text)]
```