# REGEX: Remove sentences with all greek capital letters

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I want to remove only the sentences with greek capital letters, here are some examples

```
input1 = 'Καλημέρα κόσμε' 
output = 'Καλημέρα κόσμε'
```

```
input2 = 'ΚΑΝΕΙ ΠΟΛΥ ΖΕΣΤΗ. Καθε ΣΚ.' 
Output2 = 'Καθε ΣΚ.'
```

```
input3 = 'Ο ΑΛΕΞΑΝΔΡος σπουδαζει στατιστικη' 
Output3 = 'Ο ΑΛΕΞΑΝΔΡος σπουδαζει στατιστικη'
```

I checked this previous question,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60738190/regular-expression-to-find-a-series-of-uppercase-words-in-a-string, and I created this function, but isn't working. I would be grateful if you could help me.

```
def remove_sent_capital(input):

  greek_capital_chars = set(chr(cp) for cp in range(0x0370, 0x1FFF) if "GREEK CAPITAL" in unicodedata.name(chr(cp), "")) 
  chars_class = re.escape("".join(greek_capital_chars.union(string.ascii_uppercase)))
  input = re.sub('\b[{chars_class}\s]+(?:\s+[{chars_class}\s]+)*\b', '', input)
  
  return input
```

**EDIT**: Maybe this is helpful
[image]

Comment: Can you try print `chars_class` ?

Comment: @CutePoison yeah I have done this. Why?

Comment: Let me rephrase that - can you provide the input when you call `print(chars_class)` ?

Comment: @CutePoison sure, see please again my question. I edited it.

Comment: And to be sure - you only want to remove the letter or the entire sentence, when a "great greek letter" occurs in the sentence?

Comment: @CutePoison  I want to remove only the whole sentence if all the words are capitals. See please the example 2 to understand it better.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, you want to remove the sentences where ALL letters are Greek capital. Defining a sentence as a sequence of letters finishing with '.' you can do the following:

```
def remove_sent_capital(x):
    greek_capital_chars = set(chr(cp) for cp in range(0x0370, 0x1FFF) if "GREEK CAPITAL" in unicodedata.name(chr(cp), "")) 
    s = x.split('.')
    s = [i for i in s if not all([k in greek_capital_chars for k in i if k!=' '])]
    return '.'.join(s)
```

Examples:

```
>>> remove_sent_capital('Καλημέρα κόσμε')
#'Καλημέρα κόσμε'
>>>remove_sent_capital('ΚΑΝΕΙ ΠΟΛΥ ΖΕΣΤΗ. Καθε ΣΚ.')
#' Καθε ΣΚ'
>>> remove_sent_capital('Ο ΑΛΕΞΑΝΔΡος σπουδαζει στατιστικη')
#'Ο ΑΛΕΞΑΝΔΡος σπουδαζει στατιστικη'
```

Ελπίζω να βοήθησα :)

Comment: Welcome, happy to help :)